# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - Compilation error not clear

Tags: c, gcc

The following program sorts a set of text lines into alphabetic order, a stripped - down version of the UNIX program sort.

The input routine collects and saves the characters of each line, and build an array of 
pointers to the lines. It also counts the number of input lines, since that
information is needed for sorting and printing. Since the input function can only cope with a 
finite number of input lines, it can return some illegal count like -1 if too much input is 
presented.

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 5000 /* max #lines to be sorted */

char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /* pointers to text lines */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);

/* sort input lines */
int main()
{

  int nlines; /* number of input lines read */

  if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) 
  {
    qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
    writelines(lineptr, nlines);
    return 0;
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf("error: input too big to sort\n");
    return 1;
  }

}

#define MAXLEN 1000 /* max length of any input line */

int getline(char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
/* readlines: read input lines */

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{

  int len, nlines;
  char *p, line[MAXLEN];
  nlines = 0;

  while ((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
    if (nlines >= maxlines || p = alloc(len) == NULL)
      return -1;
    else 
    {
      line[len-1] = '\0'; /* delete newline */
      strcpy(p, line);
      lineptr[nlines++] = p;
    }

  return nlines;
}

  /* writelines: write output lines */

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    printf("%s\n", lineptr[i]);
}  


/* qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order */
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right)
{

  int i, last;

  void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);
  if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
    return; /* fewer than two elements */

  swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
  last = left;
  for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
    if (strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
      swap(v, ++last, i);

  swap(v, left, last);
  qsort(v, left, last-1);
  qsort(v, last+1, right);
}

/* swap: interchange v[i] and v[j] */
void swap(char *v[], int i, int j)
{
  char *temp;

  temp = v[i];
  v[i] = v[j];
  v[j] = temp;

}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Exercises/Book/mypage108$ make
gcc -c -ansi -Wall page108.c -o page108.o
page108.c:12:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
page108.c: In function ‘readlines’:
page108.c:44:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make: *** [page108.o] Error 1
VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Exercises/Book/mypage108$ ^C
```

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: Reducing to a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org ) in the case of a syntax error is the simplest of things. You need to do it before asking here, and if you do you'll see it for yourself and won't have to wait for an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the binary operator `||` has priority over `=` in this case.
If you add a pair of brackets around `p = alloc(len)` it will solve your problem.

The result of a computation (a function call, or like here the application of an operator) is not a *left value*, i.e. cannot be used on the left side of the assignment operator.